# Printing a Count in C Only Printing to 65

Tags: c

I am trying to make a very simple 64 bit operating system, and so far have done really well, but since I am not very familiar with C I have been having some problems with it, and this one stumped me. The output would count like normal (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 etc.) but it would stop printing at 65. I know that "print.h" works because I have tested it many times, but I am not so sure on my method of converting the numbers to a character array. Any help at all would be much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
#include "print.h"

int getLen(int x) {
    unsigned int n = x;
    int count = 0;

    while(n!=0)  
   {  
       n=n/10;  
       count++;  
   }  

   return count;
}

char ITC(unsigned int x) {
    char ret;

    unsigned int n = x;
       
    if(n==0){
        ret='0';
    }
    if(n==1){
        ret='1';
    }
    if(n==2){
        ret='2';
    }
    if(n==3){
        ret='3';
    }
    if(n==4){
        ret='4';
    }
    if(n==5){
        ret='5';
    }
    if(n==6){
        ret='6';
    }
    if(n==7){
        ret='7';
    }
    if(n==8){
        ret='8';
    }
    if(n==9){
        ret='9';
    }

    return ret;

}

void kernel_main(){
    print_clear();
    print_set_color(PRINT_COLOR_GREEN, PRINT_COLOR_BLACK);

    char out[512];

    int onOut = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        onOut++;
        unsigned int n = i;
        while (n != 0) {
        
            out[onOut + getLen(n)] = ITC(n%10);
        
            n /= 10;
        }
        out[onOut + getLen(i) + 1] = '\n';
        onOut += getLen(i) + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        print_char(out[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I take it that you're not allowed to use `itoa()` from `stdlib.h`

Comment: For digits it is mandated by the standard that they are encoded in consecutive values. Therefore you can easily convert without that ton of `if`: `if (n<=9) ret=n+'0';`

Comment: In the `ITC()` function, use `return n + ‘0’;` instead of all those`if` tests.

Comment: @ChrisBD Yeah I cant use ```itoa()```

Comment: Replacing your `print.h` with the usual `stdio.h` gives me a correct printing, even if it's in done in a clumsy manner. https://ideone.com/sR7fBp Are you sure about `print.h` being implemented correctly?

Comment: You should not call `getLen` more than once per number. I don't see any reason why that code should work for `65` but not for `66`.

Comment: This creates a skipped element in your array: `onOut++;` And your `out` array is not initialized. That could confuse your print functions.

Comment: You say 1 to 64 your code suggests 0 to 100 - which is it?

Comment: @S.Ptr : It is not correct, it is simply that in your case the initialized array happened to be all NULs and printing a NUL has no effect.  In my case (on https://www.onlinegdb.com/) it contained junk characters.  Initialising `out` is good practice, but hides the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the algorithm rather then perhaps familiarity with C.  Your indexing into the *unitialised* `out` array was leaving gaps so outputting junk that happened to be in the array.

Consider the following - the parts I changed annotated - not all are part of the solution; just good practice:

```c
    char out[512] = {0};            // <<< Good idea to initialise
    int onOut = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)   // Start form 1 not zero
    {
        int n = i;                  // <<< Type agreement with i
        
        int numlen = getLen(n)  ;   // <<< Get the length of the initial number
                                    //     Don't unnecessarily calculate in the loop
                                    //     when you know it decrements by 1 on each 
                                    //     iteration
                                    
        for( int j = onOut + numlen;    // <<< Start from the end position 
             (n!=0) && j >= onOut;      // <<< toward the start position
             j-- )                      // <<< backward
        {
            out[j - 1] = ITC(n % 10);   // <<< Insert digit, starting from index zero
            n /= 10;
        }

        onOut += numlen ;           // <<< Move to end of newly inserted number
        out[onOut++] = '\n';        // <<< Add the newline
    }
```

Note that you have over-complicated this code somewhat; especially w.r.t. to `ITC()` if you code like that habitually your "*operating system*" will run very slowly.  `ITC()` can be reduced to a simple look-up thus:

```
char ITC(unsigned int x) 
{
    static const char digits[] = "0123456789" ;
    return digits[x] ;
}
```

Or in any likely character set where digits are contiguous and in order, arithmetically thus:

```
char ITC(unsigned int x) 
{
    return '0' + x ;
}
```

I'd give two pieces of advice for success in this project and programming in general.

1. Comment your code.  If you have to explain it to yourself, you are more likely to find the flaws.  But also later maintainers or people assisting you with debugging will have an idea of your intended semantics.
2. Use a debugger.  I used a [debugger](https://onlinegdb.com/Pr5sM673g) to figure out were your code was going wrong because it was quicker and more direct that other methods.  Certainly quicker than posting questions of StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you make that one function so complicated, what's wrong with this?

```
char ITC(unsigned int x) {
  return (char)((int)'0' + n);    
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question.  The OP's code is inefficient and unnecessarily complex, but not actually the problem he is asking about.  This is a comment at best (already made).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the above comments are correct, plus you also need to terminate your string with a null character... and NOT print all 512 characters of a non-initialized array. Something like this should work much better (though you should also include the contents of `print.h` so we can see if there are any problems there):

```
#include "print.h"

int getLen(unsigned int x)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (n != 0) {  
        n = n / 10;  
        count++;  
    }  
    return count;
}

char ITC(unsigned int x)
{
    return (x <= 9) ? x + '0' : '?';
}

void kernel_main()
{
    char out[512];
    int onOut = 0;

    print_clear();
    print_set_color(PRINT_COLOR_GREEN, PRINT_COLOR_BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        unsigned int len = getLen(i);
        unsigned int n = i;
        unsigned int offs = len;
        while (n != 0) {
            out[onOut + offs--] = ITC(n % 10);
            n /= 10;
        }
        out[onOut + len + 1] = '\n';
        onOut += len + 1;
    }
    out[onOut + 1] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; out[i] != 0; i++) {
        print_char(out[i]);
    }
}
```